# Duplicate answers on SO and subsequent revenge downvotes

Tags: discussion, down-votes, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887695/check-array-for-existence/4887713#4887713), the first 2 answers were by @ThiefMaster and myself. 1-2 minutes later there were 3 more answers (some got deleted), and about 5 minutes later there was another answer which was identical to most.

As it worked out, the newest answer (the one posted 5 minutes later) got up-voted. Kind of ticked me off, so I posted a comment about it. Few minutes later he gets up-voted again. This really annoyed me as non of the other answers got any upvotes, even though they'd been there 5 minutes longer. So, I down-voted that answer, because to me this is a blatant copy! He should of read the answers before posting.

So a few minutes later, I get down-voted twice (revenge down-votes) saying that I shouldn't do that and that I didn't answer the question exactly (bunch of BS).

I personally think that my down-vote was legitimate - if it was 1-2 minutes later that he posted it, I would of been fine with it, but 5 minutes later? Come on...

What do you think?

Comment: I think the level of butthurt in that question is astounding.

Comment: Haha - well, I've corrected the problem.

Comment: It's good isn't it? :p

Answer (score 17):

You posted an incomplete answer, which multiple people commented on. You replied with:

> This isn't my job - I don't get paid to meet the exact requirements of the question.

Good for the other users for posting the correct answer, no matter how much later it was; if you're not going to answer the question fully, don't expect to get upvotes, and certainly don't get mad at other people who *do* answer it completely.

As for the answers being "exact copies", they quite clearly aren't, but it wouldn't be that big of a surprise if they were; you're looping over an array and checking if the current element equals something, the code you wrote to accomplish that isn't particularly unique

Comment: Actually, ThiefMaster posted the correct answer even 15 seconds before mine, and his didn't get awarded until I down-voted the other guys.

Comment: @xil3 Er. So you're arguing that ThiefMaster's answer was best, not your own? Because it has the most upvotes and is also accepted -- it sounds like everything worked out fine

Comment: An incomplete answer? I gave a sufficient answer to point him in the right direction. Those down-votes are clearly vengeful.

Comment: @xil3 "a sufficient answer to point him in the right direction" sounds incomplete to me... Personally I don't think your answer warranted downvotes, but then again neither did the answer you downvoted. You're free to downvote as you choose though, just like the user who downvoted you

Comment: Well, regarding the 'accuracy' of the question, I've just updated it to reflect what has been said.

Comment: @xil3 Probably a good idea, although now it just looks like you copied somebody an hour later, which was of course your original problem with the whole thing. You can just delete your answer if it's wrong

Comment: I ended up deleting my answer - may as well put it behind me.

Answer (score 10):

I think that downvoting someone who answered the question more exactly than you did, *simply because* he got upvotes, is childish behavior.

Comment: Actually, I was hoping that @ThiefMaster got the one (which he did), but if I hadn't commented and down-voted that answer, he wouldn't have. I believe that credit should be given to people that deserve it. That persons answer (while it may have been more accurate to the question than mine) was an exact copy of ThiefMaster's, who answered it even before me...

Comment: @xil3: It's not a contest, there will be plenty more opportunities to draw faster then everyone else.

Comment: No it's not, but I still believe that credit should be given to people that deserve it.

Answer (score 10):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with the higher voted answers. As was pointed out to you in comments, your answer did not meet the specifics of what the OP wanted.

Regarding the 'exact copy' issue, it is not. You have to consider that several people will take a very similar path if given the same problem.

The only problem that I see is the subsequent temper tantrum that was expressed in comments. It would be more constructive if you worked on *your* answer, instead of complaining about the others so vocally.

Additionally, why did you feel compelled to be rude to the OP in the first place? That *surely* had nothing to do with it ...

Comment: Yes, but there was an answer (ThiefMaster) that was just as accurate and answered 5 minutes before, which got no credit until I down-voted the other one.

Comment: @xil3 - what makes you believe that your down vote had _anything_ to do with it? Why not just revise your answer? None of us have any control over how the community votes, that is very much by design.

Comment: Well, I just updated the answer to be more 'accurate' - doubt the down-votes will go away, though.

Comment: I'm very happy to see you on meta after the election.  Thanks for putting the effort!  And congrats on the election.

Comment: @xil3 - You'd be amazed - a helpful answer tends to collect votes over time. I also suggest removing some of your more abrasive comments, especially the one asking the OP how they got over 1k rep. That just serves to sour people, regardless of the validity of your answer.

Comment: I ended up deleting my answer - may as well put it behind me.

Comment: @xil3 - Thanks for also cleaning up the flame war. I'm quite certain that you'll enjoy harder problems to solve in the future.